# Separate machines for DBMS and SSIS, SSRS, SQL Agent?

Tags: database, architecture, ssis

We have two DB boxes. We would like to keep our application DB on one server and on the other server we would like to have SSIS, SSRS and SQL Agent. Are there any performance issues when doing this? Or are there any recommendations associated with this? Given we need to install Oracle driver, Office driver etc...

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Oracle or both?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 potential issues with this approach:

- You will need a MS SQL Licence for both machines, so higher cost
- If the SSIS packages are accessing the database they will be pulling data across the network instead of handling it locally on the machine

What you have not said is why you want to do this?